# Google Play Error 400 when resuming track

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-console, testtrack

## My problem

I am trying to start the BETA track in the open test category.
But in order to get this working I need to start the track first obviously. Whenever I try to do that, it says "unknown error. please try again later (some error code)".

## What I already tried

I "accidently" created a release before the track was started, because I didn't notice it wasn't running. That release was supposed to be the first one on this track as well as in the "open beta" category.

So I tried using incognito mode. No success.

## What I noticed

Whenever I click the "start rack" button, the console prints out an error saying the server answered with a code 400(bad request). I don't understand why

What can I do about this?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try to remove all drafts

Comment: I guess this is a bug in the Play Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Play Console, and I have just reported it to the Play Console team.

---

However, once you create a release using the "Create new release" button, you will be able to resume the track.